# Java CDI instance inject on generic type

Tags: java, cdi, inject, generic-type-argument

i want to write generic validator objects that can be injected runtime chosing a concrete type bean to valide but i can't get injection working. Here are the interfaces classes:

```
public interface GenericValidator<T> {

    String getConfigurationCode();

    ErrorMessages validate(T toValidate);
}

public class GenericValidatorConstructor<T>  {

    @Inject
    private Instance<GenericValidator<T>> delegators;

    public List<GenericValidator<T>> getValidatorsByConfig(String configCode) {
        List<GenericValidator<T>> result = new ArrayList<GenericValidator<T>>();
        for (GenericValidator<T> validator : delegators) {
            if (configCode != null && configCode.equals(validator.getConfigurationCode()) ) {
                result.add(validator);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

then i've implemente a concrete class with a String reference like this:

```
@Override
public String getConfigurationCode() {
    return "GENERIC_PASSWORD";
}

@Override
public ErrorMessages validate(String toValidate) {
    return null;
}
```

In a stateless ejb i've injected this way

```
@Inject
private GenericValidatorConstructor<String> passwordValidatorConstructor;
```

and then invoked the method

```
passwordValidatorConstructor.getValidatorsByConfig("GENERIC_PASSWORD");
```

but inside the `getValidatorsByConfig Instance<GenericValidator<T>>` delegators is an empty collection and i don't know why. What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
@Inject  
private Instance<GenericValidator<T>> delegators;
```

with:

```
@Any 
@Inject 
private Instance<GenericValidator<?>> delegators;
```

Then the Instance injection will be able to inject all implementations of your `GenericValidator`, and then you can use `GenericValidator.getConfigurationCode` to select the appropriate type, or use `Instance.select(TypeLiteral<MyConcreteType>{})` to select the appropriate concrete type

Comment: Thanks i can get to retrieve the implementations this way but now i can't invoke validate as it expects to have a T; the error at compilation time is The method validate(capture#1-of ?) in the type GenericValidator<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (String). So i changed a bit the method getConfigurationCode typecasting validator loop variable. Is any chances to avoid type safety warning?